# Create http request to upload and get file from s3 base api gateway aws

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have made a method to request API Gateway AWS to PUT and load to upload a binary file to s3.

I have created some common methods to create Authorization header like this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=819688

my example api link like this: https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/api/bucket/file.txt

```
string[] uriSplit = urlApi.Split('/');              
            string host = uriSplit[2];
            string canonicalUri ="/" + uriSplit[3];               
            string hashedRequestPayload = Utils.CreateRequestPayload(dataFile);

            string authorization = Utils.Sign(hashedRequestPayload, "PUT", canonicalUri, string.Empty,
                                              ContentType.ApplicationOctetStream, AWSRegionName.AsiaPacificTokyo,
                                              AWSCommon.APIGateWayServiceName, host);
            string requestDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") + "Z";

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlApi);

            request.Timeout = timeout;
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = ContentType.ApplicationOctetStream;
            request.Headers.Add("X-Amz-Date", requestDate);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);                

            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(dataFile, 0, dataFile.Length);
            }

            // GetResponse
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (responseStream != null && responseStream.CanRead)
                {
                    // Get response WebResponse
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        // Parse to string result
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                return ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
            }
```

I always receive status code 403 servers forbidden.
How can I create the canonicalUri and canonicalQueryString base the request URL?

and what I mistake to create the HTTP request to API gateway AWS?

Comment: first check proper access configured is or not in IAM and AWS credentials configured properly . Your api gateway should have access to s3 bucket as well.Try hitting the request using postman or any http Client. I would suggest creating a get request first and check if you are getting response. Try the same for put as well. If you get a response in client then possible error in your code. cross verify below:Host: randomvalue.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com. Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={access-key-id}/date/{region}/execute-api/aws4_request.